# ModX Evo places page name in image path URL. How to disable this?

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce, modx, modx-evolution

I just upgraded a site from 1.0.5 to 1.0.12 and am having troubles with images. It seems that now when I save a resource, ModX or TinyMCE places the name of the resource in the path for whatever images I have in that resource.

So, formally, my image paths looked like:

```
www.mysite.com/assets/images/photo.jpg
```

but now they look like:

```
www.mysite.com/page-name/assets/images/photo.jpg
```

This has broken all the images on my site. Further more, adding a new image or finding the old ones via the file browser doesnt work either. It just inserts them with the proper path, but updates them with the new path upon save, having the same effect.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify "base url" in "head" tag - `<base href="http://your_site.com/" >`